# How to show a form with focused appearance but not focused?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus, themes

How is it possible to make a form seem focused when it's not?
In my code the form can't be focused, so it always looks not focused and my aim is to show it with focused style.
The solution may be applying a special theme to the form, but I'm not sure.
(I'm using c# .NET)

Comment: You will have to be more specific.  Simply asking to subvert standard Windows behavior will get you nowhere.  Precisely what about it would you change?  I can tell you straight away you're in for some pain.  Perhaps you need to rethink your form design before you try hacking the visuals to pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surely you mean *activated*, a form is a top-level window that almost never gets the focus.  One of its client controls gets it.  Window activation affects the colors of the window's caption bar, presumably you always want it drawn with the "I'm active" colors.  Older versions of Paint.NET used this hack for its tool windows.

Windows sends the WM_NCACTIVATE message to a window to get it to display the proper activation state.  The wparam of the message indicates what system colors it should use for its caption bar, TRUE indicates the active state.  You can simply tinker with the message and always force the wparam value.  It is a one-liner, paste this code into your form class:

```
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) {
        if (m.Msg == 0x86) m.WParam = (IntPtr)1;
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

I can't guarantee this won't have any side effects.  Afaik it only affects the painting, you still get the Deactivate event for example.